# Passing firebase information through factory error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, factory

Alright my AngularJS Mates.. I need saving. The following is my code. As you can see i'm trying to like pass the firebase data through states, unfortunately 'Offer' is only displaying as '[]' I think this is because i'm using a $firebaseObject, but i just cant crack this code... 
(yeah I totally stole a part of this from Codepen)

Legit i would get your address and send you roses if you fixed this for me.

My Factory:

```
.factory('PetService', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {


  var ref = new Firebase("https://idargo.firebaseio.com/userData")
  var offer = ref.child('Offer');

  var pets = [];

  for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    pets[i] = {
      id: i,
      'Name': 'Name' + i,
      'Offer': $firebaseObject(offer)
    };

  }

  return {
    all: function () {
      return pets;
    },
    get: function (petId) {

      return pets[petId];
    }
  };

})
```

DashCtrl:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, PetService) {
      $scope.pets = PetService.all();
})
```

ProfileCtrl:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($stateParams, PetService) {
   $scope.pet = PetService.get($stateParams.petsId);
})
```

The State:

```
  .state('app.profile', {
    url: "/profile/:petsId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "routes/profile.html",
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
      }
    }
  })
```

The Collection-Repeat:

```
<div class="col"  collection-repeat="pet in pets" item-width="45%" item-height="35%" ui-sref="app.profile({petsId: pet.id })">
```

The Profile Html:

```
<div ng-cloak>
<ion-view title="{{pet.id}}">

<div class="bar bar-header loginbar">
<button class="button button-icon ion-ios-arrow-left loginhead" ui-sref="app.dash"></button>
<h1 class="title"></h1>
</div>

  <ion-content>
    <div>
      <center>
      <div class="top2">
        <div class="wrapperinv">
            <div style="padding-top: 15%"></div>

            <div class="numberCircle">
                <div class="height_fix"></div>

                <div class="content"><img src="{{pet.Image}}" class="invoiceimage"></div>
            </div>


            <div style="margin-top: -100px;"></div>

            <div class="mincirc">
                <div style="margin-top: 8px;"></div>
                <div class="rotate"><i class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline invi"></i></div>
            </div>

            <div class="mincirc2" ui-sref="app.chat">
                <div style="margin-top: 8px;"></div>
                <div class="rotate"><i class="icon ion-ios-chatbubble-outline invi" ></i></div>
            </div>

            <div style="margin-top: 100px;"></div>
            <label class="sometext">{{pet.firstName}}</label>

            <div style="margin-top: -50px;"></div>

            <h3>
                <i class="ion-star invstar invi"></i> <i class="ion-star invstar invi"></i>
                <i class="ion-star invstar invi"></i> <i class="ion-star invstar invi"></i>
                <i class="ion-star invstar invi"></i>
            </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </center>

            <div style="margin-top: -10px;"></div>

      <div class="list" >
      <label class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-earth"></i>
       <h4 class="invf">Location</h4>
       <div class="invtext">{{pet.Name}}</div>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-calendar"></i>
        <h4 class="invf">Age</h4>
        <div class="invtext">{{pet.Age}}</div>
      </label>
       <label class="item item-icon-left"  style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 350px;">    
       <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
        <h4 class="invf">About me</h4>
        <div class="invtext" >{{item.About}}</div>
      </label>
       <label class="item item-icon-left">
       <i class="icon ion-pizza"></i>
       <h4 class="invf" >What I offer</h4>
          <div class="invtext">{{pet.Offer}}</div>
      </label>
       <label class="item item-icon-left">
      <i class="icon ion-cash"></i>
        <h4 class="invf">Rate</h4>
        <div class="invtext">{{item.Rate}}</div>
      </label>
      </div>

            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d150038.30908416258!2d-74.00164182706976!3d40.64734690331712!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew+York%2C+NY%2C+USA!5e1!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1440975673055" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>

      <button class="button button-block invbut" ng-click="invoice()">
      Book With {{item.Name}}
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

-Sorry if my English is bad... i'm from Australia.

Comment: You seem to be calling get() without an itemId.

Comment: Can you post your profile.html please?

Comment: Sure... Just updated it... Thanks so much for your reply x